# Removing headline beamer, insert frame title instead

Tags: beamer, headline

I would like to remove the headline of all `frame` after the frame "Annexes" without removing the footline. I want the frame title take place of headline.

Is it possible ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\AtBeginSection{\begin{frame}[plain]
\usebeamertemplate{section page}
\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\section{title} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{Annexes}   
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\section{title} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{Annexes}   
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\makeatletter
\beamer@calculateheadfoot
\makeatother
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

---

Update: with the [current beamer development version](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/0c4118b00dcb1ece7f5185805cb1f8164f7d0b6b), this workaround should no longer be necessary, as beamer now calculates the head- and footheight at the start of every frame. This should be included in beamer v3.70 (or newer)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 

Comment: @Tony You're welcome! For future questions, please add a small, but compilable text document.